# Helicon Tech - ISAPI_Rewrite: RewriteRule's for specific domains

Tags: url-rewriting

Could someone help me translate the following pseudo-code into code understood by [Helicon Tech's ISAPI_Rewrite module](http://www.isapirewrite.com/):

```
if (domain == something.com OR domain == www.something.com)
{
    // The rules inside this scope will only apply to the domain:
    // something.com / www.something.com

    // This should match "something.com/test" and/or "www.something.com/test"
    RewriteRule /something /something/something.aspx
}


if (domain == test.com OR domain == www.test.com)
{
    // The rules inside this scope will only apply to the domain:
    // test.com / www.test.com

    // This should match "test.com/test" and/or "www.test.com/test"
    RewriteRule /test /test/test.aspx
}
```

The [documentation](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) is very confusing to me.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the effort Gumbo and Tomalak. Really appreciate it.

I've figured out another approach though: you put a file (httpd.ini) holding specific rewrite's to a specific virtual directory/domain in the root folder of that virtual directory/domain.

This eliminates polluting the global config file as well.

Comment: How is that connected to your question? :-)

Answer (score 3):

If ISAPI_Rewrite works the same as Apache’s mod_rewrite, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?something\.example$
RewriteRule ^/something$ /something/something.aspx

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.example$
RewriteRule ^/test$ /test/test.aspx
```

Note: I used other domain names according to [RFC 2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt).

---

**Edit:** It seems that for ISAPI_Rewrite you have to replace the `%{HTTP_HOST}` by [`Host:`](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#RewriteCond) to get the current host.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "old" syntax, used before version 3:

```
RewriteCond Host: ^(www\.)?something\.com$
RewriteRule ^/something$ /something/something.aspx

RewriteCond Host: ^(www\.)?something\.com$
RewriteRule ^/test$ /test/test.aspx
```

This would be the new syntax, for version 3 and up. This is closer to mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(www\.)?something\.com$
RewriteRule ^/something$ /something/something.aspx

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(www\.)?something\.com$
RewriteRule ^/test$ /test/test.aspx
```

The regex itself is the same in both versions.

Comment: I think the new syntax should be %{HTTP_HOST} (underscore instead of colon).

Comment: This is what their own syntax converter tool gave me.

Comment: Not so fast: %{HTTP:Host} accesses the raw header, whereas %{HTTP_HOST} accesses a server variable. Not every header has a corresponding server variable, but in this case they should both contain the same value. (I believe mod_rewrite cannot access the headers at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note that the per-directory httpd.ini method described above is not supported by the ISAPI 3 light version: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/litever.htm